# notifications on top of a group chat

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

On the top of the group chat there is nearly a 3 page long list of who left group or joined or change in group subject..icon etc...Is there a way to delete these lines from the chat without deleting the entire chat? When selecting individual messages to delete you cannot select these lines

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no way for selecting/deleting these information in group chat.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered how to do it...star the messages you dont want deleted from a chat and then use the "clear chat" option making sure that your "keep the starred messages" option is ticked. When you clear the chat these messages get cleared.